# How to resolve undefined type in pyi file?

Tags: python, python-typing, pyi

I'm manually creating a pyi file for one of my classes and one of its function return types relies on an enum I made in another file.

Relevant code snippets: `Board.pyi`

```py
class Board:
    def access(self, i: int, j: int) -> Color: ...
```

Where `Color` is the enum. To resolve the fact that `Color` is not defined in the pyi file, should I just import it from `Color.py` / `Color.pyi` or is there another solution that's detailed by PEP?

Comment: What happens if you try to import it?

Comment: `from stubs.color import Color` works but I don't know if that's what you're supposed to do if there's anything referenced in the PEPs

Answer (score -1):

You can use a normal `import` statement to bring in any types you need in your `.pyi` file. The official type stub [documentation](https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/stubs.html) has this as an example:

```py
from typing_extensions import Literal

def foo(x: Literal[""]) -> int: ...
```